# Is it possible to create AWS CloudFormation template, that will create a stack with the CREATE_FAILED status

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, aws-cloudformation

For testing reasons I need to deploy a failed stack via CloudFormation (with CREATE_FAILED status), but when I try to mess with the CloudFormation template, it stops me on the template validator. I believe that it is possible to create a template, that will pass the validator but fail when deployed. Can someone give me an example? (Free tier examples will be the best ones)

Comment: Probably create an S3 bucket which already exists?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if resource was trying to create and it failed. It may fail if it was there already, it may fail because of API error. It may fail if e.g. you create lambda with concurrency 100000 and you don't have that available on your account. You should see the reason inside cloudformation console OR if you used cli, just don't terminate the process in cli and it will show the reasons. Yet sometimes, especially when using sub-stacks i find more useful info in aws console itself.